# Adding dollar prefix to bootstrap input box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there anyway bootstrap way/style to add non-editable prefix into the inputbox? such as the dollar sign. the prefix has to be included inside the input box.

currently I'm doing something like this, but the sign is out of the inputbox.

```
<div class="input-group input-medium ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" readonly="">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        $
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bootstrap Versions 4 and 5

This functionality changed significantly between versions 3 and 4. The class `input-group-addon` has been removed in favor of using `input-group-text` inside of either `input-group-prepend` or `input-group-append`.

**To prepend text**

```html
<!-- importing Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" />
</div>
```

**To append text**

```html
<!-- importing Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">@gmail.com</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**To change the background color of the added text**

```
.input-group-text
{
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work properly in BS5 - the prepended input ends up with rounded corners on the right.  Correct code for BS5 is here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/#basic-example

Answer (score 95):

Twitter Bootstrap Version 3 has a class named `input-group-addon` for this feature.

You probably want this

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="price">
</div>
```

[<kbd>Js Fiddle Demo - Basic</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/1/)

Update: To remove the background from the `$` sign- You just need to overwrite the `input-group-addon` class

```
.input-group-addon
{
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

[<kbd>Js Fiddle Demo - Without Background</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/2/)

If you want to remove the border from right side of `$` sign, You can add this css as well

```
.input-group .input-group-addon + .form-control
{
    border-left:none;
}
```

[<kbd>Js Fiddle Demo - Without Border</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/3/)

Comment: This is great but I prefer to remove the grey background from the dollar sign.

Comment: @TanJitRen You can very easily remove the background from the dollar sign by overwriting the class. Look at the updates in my post and here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s6Xu6/2/

Comment: nice use of `<kbd>---</kbd>` tag

Answer (score 20):

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6" >
    <div class="left-inner-addon">
        <span>$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6" >
    <div class="right-inner-addon">
        <span>$</span>
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" />
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}
.left-inner-addon input {
    padding-left: 22px;    
}
.left-inner-addon span {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.right-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}
.right-inner-addon input {
    padding-right: 30px;    
}
.right-inner-addon span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/rbsthlm/qE9kJ/)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need. If twitter bootstrap included this, it will be great.

Comment: You're welcome! Got a feeling that you didn't want the standard solution already provided by BS... :)

Comment: js fiddle demo broken not found

Answer (score 0):

You can to this by setting the `input-group` a `position:relative` and `absolute positioning` the `input` and the `span` with higher(than input's z-index) `z-index` number for span. 
Also you need to add to the `input` a `padding-left` value equal to `span`'s width